# String with an interchangeable letter

Tags: c++, string, function

The directions for my assignment are as follows:

Return the number of times that the string "hope" appears anywhere in the given string, except we'll accept any letter for the 'p', so "hode" and "hooe" count.

I am struggling to figure out how to make the third letter equal anything and still have the program identify that it is correct.

**My code so far is quite obviously wrong but ill include it nonetheless.**

one big problem is i can't tell the array to check if it matches the string.

```
int wordsFunction(string words)
{
int num = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < words.length(); i++)
{
    if(words[i] == "Hope" || words[i] == "hope")
    {
        num++;
    }
}
return num;
}

main()
{
string words;
cout << "Enter a string: ";
getline(cin, words);
cout << wordsFunction(words);
```

Comment: If `words` is `string`, `words[i]` is a `char` and you can't compare it with an array of chars as `"hope"`. Look for the substring "ho" and then check if the 4th letter is an 'e'.

Comment: Your code won't work. Hint: you are comparing variables with incompatible ( as a rough approximation: different ) types. In programmig that's like comparing apples with bananas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My code so far is quite obviously wrong

That is true. I wouldn't explain why your code is wrong, and go straight to a description of a fix.

Your `main` reads the string that allows spaces, which is good: the I/O part of your code does not need to be changed.

Now observe that to detect the word `"ho*e"`, with `*` denoting any single character, at a position `i` in a word `w`, you need to check that `w[i]` is an `'h'`, `w[i+1]` is an `'o'`, `w[i+3]` is an `'e'`, and that the index `i+3` is valid. This becomes a simple check:

```
if (i+3 < w.size() && w[i] == 'h' && w[i+1] == 'o' && w[i+3] == 'e') {
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Nice.now it would be also better to make this program case(upper and lower) proof.

Comment: @MudassirHussain The code the OP posted suggests that the first letter of `"ho*e"` could be in uppercase, but the text of the question does not support this assumption. Of course a simple fix for this is to convert `w` to lowercase before searching.